# Extracting overlapping year-like looking parts from text using R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract all year-like looking phrases from a text with different patterns using R.

I want to catch all following patterns:
`[Nothing OR non-digit][Year-like looking part][Nothing OR non-digit]`

For example:
`"1987-1998x2002"` should give `"1987-", "-1998x", "x2002"`

But my code fails to catch -1985x:

```
try <- "1987-1985x2002"
regmatches(try, gregexpr("((^|\\D)1(6|7|8|9)\\d\\d($|\\D))|((^|\\D)20(0|1|2)\\d($|\\D))", try))

[[1]]
[1] "1987-" "x2002"
```

I also don't understand why matching a phrase is dependent on matching an earlier phrase. For example, once I delete the first character of the above example, I get a totally different thing.

```
try <- "987-1985x2002"
regmatches(try, gregexpr("((^|\\D)1(6|7|8|9)\\d\\d($|\\D))|((^|\\D)20(0|1|2)\\d($|\\D))", try))
[[1]]
[1] "-1985x"
```

I want it to catch

```
"-1985x", "x2002"
```

As if the gregexpr function removes the whole phrase for the remaining search once a match is achieved.

Comment: It appears from your regex that "year-like looking phrases" refers to years in the range "1600-2029", but that's not stipulated. It should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern contains `(^|\D)` pattern at  the start and `($|\D)` pattern at the end of each matching alternative. These are [*capturing groups*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that consume text, i.e. adding matched texts to the overall matches and advancing regex index. Since the `1987-` is the first match, the `-` is consumed and is not available for the next match, the next match occurs is thus `x2002`.

You want to use a positive lookahead with a single capturing group inside:

```
try <- "1987-1985x2002"
res <- stringr::str_match_all(try, "(?=((?:\\D|^)(?:1[6-9]\\d{2}|20[0-2]\\d)(?:\\D|$)))")
lapply(res, function(x) x[,-1])
```

Output:

```
[1] "1987-"  "-1985x" "x2002"
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/ACO46023)

**Regex details**

- `(?=` - a positive lookahead:

  - `(` - start of a capturing group:

    - `(?:\D|^)` - non-digit char or start of string
    - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

      - `1[6-9]\d{2}` - `1`, a digit from 6 to 9 and then any two digits
      - `|` - or
      - `20[0-2]\d` - `20`, a digit from 0 to 2 and then any one digit
    - `)` - end of the non-capturing group
    - `(?:\D|$)` - non-digit char or end of string
  - `)` - end of the capturing group #1
- `)` - end of the positive lookahead.

Comment: How can I get "1987-" "-1985x" "x2002" as output?

Comment: @Baris Those are *overlapping* matches. You can get them using positive lookarounds with capturing groups inside them.